# Add custom meta data after Payment confirmation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, orders

I was looking around the web for a solution to add the response from the payment gateway I am using.

I would like to add the verification code I get and some more data. I need to add this once the payment is complete.

```
// Payment complete
$order->payment_complete($payment_id);
```

I did try this code but does not work for me:

```
   add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 
        'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

    function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
         update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', 'test');
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better use dedicated woocommerce_payment_complete action hook this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_update_order_meta', 20, 1 );
function custom_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
     update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', 'test');
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

This should works.

---

For A plugin you will need to add this first in the `__construct()` function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', array( $this 'custom_update_order_meta'), 20, 1 );
```

And then something like:

```
public function custom_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
     update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', 'test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks It is not in a theme it has to be in a plugin.

Comment: @DaniEvanRubenstien For a plugin, it doesn't change so much… see my update…