# Convert result to a array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello to All i get a result from a server like this.

> Id=6528537&CCode=250&Fild1=&Fild2=&Fild3=&HeshASM=0

How Can i convert it into a arary in php.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: please fix your question; it contains too many spelling mistakes and won't help in a (Google) search. Edit: someone else did it for you (kind of), as did someone else did it for you in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262726/add-custom-meta-data-after-payment-confirmation-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = 'Id=6528537&CCode=250&Fild1=&Fild2=&Fild3=&HeshASM=0';
parse_str($query, $output);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';

/*
Array
(
    [Id] => 6528537
    [CCode] => 250
    [Fild1] => 
    [Fild2] => 
    [Fild3] => 
    [HeshASM] => 0
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to construct the array yourself:

```
$string = "Id=6528537&CCode=250&Fild1=&Fild2=&Fild3=&HeshASM=0";
$explode = explode("&", $string);
$array = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $inner_explode = explode("=", $value);
    $array[$inner_explode[0]] = $inner_explode[1];
}
```

You would explode the string using "&" as separator, that will give you an array with the different parameters like `array('id=6528537','ccode=250'...)`

Then you will iterate trough that array, and explode again, this time using "=" as separator, this will give you the different parts of the different parameters, like: `array('Id','6528537')`.

Knowing that in the position 0 of that array you will have the key, and in the position 1 the value, you simply add to your array the values in each iteration with `$array[$inner_explode[0]] = $inner_explode[1];`